# SQL - How do i use a selected ID in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL TABLES:
user = ID, name, email..
hero = ID, name, level..
owner = userid, heroid

I have these two queries:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT heroid FROM owner WHERE userid='$id'"); 
$heroid=mysql_fetch_row($result); 
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM hero WHERE ID = 'heroid[0]'");

$heroname = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
echo "User $id has a character named $heroname[0]";
$heroname = mysql_fetch_row($result2); 
echo "User $id has a character named $heroname[0]";
..
```

Can this be done with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. you can do:

```sql
SELECT h.name
FROM hero h
INNER JOIN owner o ON o.heroid = h.id
WHERE o.userid = $id
```